# Some of the files disappear after extracting zip files in google drive through Google Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory, delete-file, unzip, training-data

I am using Google colab to train my model therefore I have uploaded the dataset in zip format to google drive. Whenever I used the following command to extract dataset in the google drive, some of the folders in the dataset become disappear after signing out from google drive.

!unzip -q [file.zip] -d [destination]

The above mentioned command works perfectly

Comment: Hi ! What are you using to run that command? Also, while you are on your google drive and unzip the folder, are you able to see all the expected files? How are you using **Google Drive API** in this situation?